# If $X$ is an $n \times p$ matrix, under what conditions is $X^TX-\frac{1}{n}X^T\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^TX$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $X$ is an $n \times p$ matrix, under what conditions is $X^TX-\frac{1}{n}X^T\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^TX$ invertible? I am assuming that $X$ is an invertible matrix itself. I have tried to do the following but dont know why it doesn't work:

$$
\left(X^TX-\frac{1}{n}X^T\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^TX\right) v =0
$$

so that

$$
\left(X-\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^TX\right) v =0
$$

by taking inverse of $X^T$. However, this is a singular matrix so I am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Is $X$ a column vector (and the question is about invertibility of a scalar)?

Comment: What is $11^T$?

Comment: How $n\times p$ matrix is invertible?

Comment: @Ruzayqat The sensible interpretation would be that $\mathbb 1$ is the all-ones vector, so that $\frac1n \mathbb{11}^T$ is the all-ones matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix is invertible iff
$$
\left(X^TX-\frac{1}{n}X^T\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^TX\right) v =0\quad\Rightarrow\quad v=0.
$$
Pre-multiplying by $v^T$ and introducing the notation $Xv=w$ we get
$$
w^T\left(I-\frac1n 1 1^T\right)w=0.\tag{1}
$$
The matrix $I-\frac1n 1 1^T$ is positive semidefinite. It can be checked e.g. by [Sylvester criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion) or just by verifying that
$$
w^T\left(I-\frac1n 1 1^T\right)w=\|w\|^2-\frac1n\Big(\sum_{k=1}^nw_i\Big)^2\ge 0
$$
since $\sum w_i\le\|w\|\sqrt{n}$ from [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). For semidefinite matrices (1) implies
$$
\Big(I-\frac1n 1 1^T\Big)w=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad w=\frac{1^Tw}{n}\cdot 1.\tag{2}
$$
It gives directly that $w\parallel 1$, i.e. $w=c\cdot 1$. For invertibility we need, thus, that $Xv=c\cdot 1$ must have only zero solutions $v$ and $c$ $\Leftrightarrow $

> the vector $1$ and the columns of $X$ are linearly independent.